# how to put widgets into tabs to control the plots in the tab

Tags: python, widget, bokeh

I am trying to organize my widgets and plots in tabs. Below code and screenshot is what I got. I need to put widget select4tab1 in tab1 to control plot1 and plot2; put widget select4tab2 in tab2 to control plot3 and plot4.

Can anyone help me out please?
Thanks 
[image]

```
from ipywidgets import interact, interact_manual

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook, push_notebook
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot
from bokeh.layouts import row, column, layout
from bokeh.models import CategoricalColorMapper, HoverTool, ColumnDataSource, Panel,FactorRange,LabelSet
from bokeh.models.widgets import CheckboxGroup, Slider, RangeSlider, Tabs,TableColumn, DataTable


output_notebook()


data=[['a',1,6],['a',2,6],['a1',1,3],['a1',2,8],['b',1,11],['b',2,3],['b1',1,21],['b1',2,4]]
df1=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['group','time','rate'])
df2=df1

@interact
def plot(select4tab1=['a','a1','b','b1'],
         select4tab2=['a','a1','b','b1']):

    data4tab1=df1.loc[(df1.group==select4tab1) ]
    p1=figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=300)
    p1.line(data4tab1.time, data4tab1.rate)

    p2=figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=300)
    p2.circle(data4tab1.time, data4tab1.rate)

    data4tab2=df2.loc[(df2.group==select4tab2) ]
    p3=figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=300)
    p3.line(data4tab2.time, data4tab2.rate,color='red')

    p4=figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=300)
    p4.circle(data4tab2.time, data4tab2.rate,color='red')


    grid1=layout([[p1,p2]])
    tab1=Panel(child=grid1,title='tab1') 


    grid2=layout([[p3,p4]])
    tab2 = Panel(child = grid2, title = 'tab2')



    tabs=Tabs(tabs=[tab1,tab2])
    show(tabs)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not possible, as Bokeh widgets and `ipywidgets` do not generally work together or integrate at all. To accomplish what you want you should use Bokeh `Select` widgets, and [embed everything as a Bokeh server app in the notebook](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/howto/server_embed/notebook_embed.ipynb). I doubt there is any other solution.